# Want to create variable looping like these $H[count]

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with my variable, I wanna make variable like these

```
$H1,H2, until $h48
```

but I know is kinda difficult, so I wanna change to like these

```
$H[1],$H[2],$H[3] until $H[48]
```

these I try with my code:

```
$loopCount = 1;
        $H = array();
        for ($loopCount = 1; $loopCount<49; $loopCount=$loopCount + 1)
        {
            $H[$loopCount] = 0;
        }
```

But it is not working at all. How to make it work?? Any idea??

EDIT RESOLVED : Thanks To Ghost helping me out.

Here my revisi code :

```
$H = array();
            for ($loopCount = 1; $loopCount<49; $loopCount=$loopCount + 1)
            {
                $H{$loopCount} = 0;
            }
```

And just call $H{1} , is complete work. Thanks again to Ghost you're hero :)

Comment: why would you do that? an array with numeric index is a much better idea

Comment: @nogad Is kinda take a long time if i create $H1 until $H48, i mean i wanna to make easier.

Comment: using `[]` denotes it as an array index, what you want is called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), `$H{$loopcount}`, and in the future, just use arrays, you already said so yourself

Comment: @Ghost Ohhh.. You right!! Sorry i'm kinda new bie of these coding with array, btw thanks/ again :)

Comment: speed would be no difference at all `$a = array_fill(0, 48, '0);`

Comment: @Wolfzmus, would you accept an answer which was a perfect solution?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay i was get answer from Ghost. Not from you. so why i need accept from your question even i get answer from Ghost??

Comment: @Wolfzmus I did not say to accept my answer.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay really?? You said "would you accept an answer which was a perfect solution?"

Comment: yes, whatever answer was helpful and perfect solution, I asked to accept that.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this :

```
$loopCount = 1;
$H = '';
for ($loopCount = 1; $loopCount<48; $loopCount=$loopCount + 1)
{
    ${"H" . $loopCount} = 0;
}
```